# inline_formset missing field

Tags: django

I've added inline_formset. But `{{ form.name }}` its not showing in template. Am i missing something? thanks

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(('album name'), max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=('user'), related_name=('users'))

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, verbose_name=('album'), related_name=('songs'))
    title = models.CharField(('song name'), max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(('artist name'), max_length=100)
```

inline_formset

```
AlbumFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Album, Song)
```

in template

```
   <tr>
      <td>{{ form.name }}</td> <-- its not showing
      <td>{{ form.title }} </td>
      <td>{{ form.artist }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

{{ formset.management_form }}
```

UPDATE

```
                 {% for form in formset %}
                    <tr>

                      <td>{{ form.title }} </td>
                      <td>{{ form.artist }} </td>
                      <td>{{album_form.name}}</td>
                      <td>{{ form.errors }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

I've added separate ModelForm for Album then added within forloop. NOw its repeating input tag name. `<input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="100">`

Latest Update

I've added following data. Data is saved. But there is a strange problem. Only `Last Album` is saving not `Test 1` and `Test 2`.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that inlineformset does not include a form for Album Model. You have to create a separate ModelForm for Album and then do something like `{{album_form.name}}`.

You can associate you formsets with the ForeignKey to the Album with Something like this in you view-

```
# validation and other code
# ---------------------------
new_album = Album()
new_album_form = AlbumModelForm(request.POST,instance=new_album)
song_formset = AlbumFormset(request.POST)
new_album_form.save()
songs = song_formset.save(comit=False)
for song in songs:
    song.album = new_album
    song.save()
```

**EDIT:**

The above solution may work if you want to create one Album and multiple Songs with foreign key to that album. To get what you wanted ie `{{form.name}}`,`{{form.title}}` and `{{form.artist}}` use normal formset with name,title and artist fields instead of modelformset.

Comment: i think you are right. If I create a separate ModelForm for Album. Then how can i associate their data? because I've applied foreign key to `Album`. How do I've to save the data?

Comment: ok I've added separate ModelForm for Album. Then `{{album_form.name}}` within `formset` forloop. But its repeating input tag name `<input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="100">`. How do i get rid of this problem?

Comment: I have updated the ans with a sample snipest. I think it may work.

Comment: thanks alot. But I am getting strange  problem. Will you please take look? thanks. question updated.

Comment: Sorry. I was Assuming that you want to create one Album and multiple Songs instead of multiple Songs each with name field. Probably you can   play with loops and use modelformset instead of ModelForm for Album. But I personally think for this case you should use a custom/normal formset (not modelformset)  with name, title and artist FormFields or change structure of your page to 'single album multiple songs' form (even Django admin uses this approach for creating/editing foreign keyed objects with inlines).

Comment: thanks. If i use normal formset with name,title and artist fields. Can I read name(album) then save to album model? It will be very tedious work.

Comment: To save name/album you can do something like `new_album = Album(name=album_form.cleaned_data['name']); new_album.save()`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `name` field in the form. The form is for Songs, and they have `album`, `title` and `artist`.